# Install TYPO3 under a symlink (Platform.sh)

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I'm trying to install TYPO3 using a symlink structure based on platform.sh.

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 4.0K Feb 13 11:58 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant    0 Feb 13 11:17 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 1.2K Feb 10 15:29 composer.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  72K Feb 10 15:29 composer.lock
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 4.0K Feb 10 15:29 .git
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  193 Feb 10 15:29 .gitignore
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  35K Feb 10 15:29 LICENSE
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  716 Feb 10 15:29 Makefile
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   95 Feb 10 15:29 php.ini
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant    0 Feb 10 15:29 .platform
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 3.2K Feb 10 15:29 .platform.app.yaml
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 2.0K Feb 10 15:29 README.md
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 4.0K Feb 10 15:39 vendor
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 4.0K Feb 13 11:30 web
lrwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant    0 Feb 10 15:39 _www -> .platform/local/builds/default/web
```

But I always get the following message:

```
/ is not a directory
Directory / should be a directory, but is of type link
```

This happens because the Class DirectoryNode uses

```
return !@is_link($path) && @is_dir($path);
```

to identify directorys and it does not match on symlinks.

I'm looking forward to your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_www/typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php is a dead symlink to writable/LocalConfiguration.php

It seems to be a bug.

Temporary solution: Remove Symlink (Installtool will create it on its own)

Answer (score 0):

You mean the warning in the Install Tool? You can actually ignore that as it is a false positive, everything works out just fine.

Comment: This was my also my first thought, but I can't get to the next step.
The page reloads and still the same message. If I click the "I know what I'm doing"-Button the second time, the Installationtool wants me to create the FIRST_INSTALL file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error once, a long time ago. If I remember that correctly, I had to clear the opcode cache in the install tool.

Comment: But this happens while installing TYPO3.
Ignoring this Message doesn't take me to the next step but back to the first again.